# Outlook 2007 never seems to shut down when instructed to

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2007

Currently working on a VBScript to automate some of the dirty PST ingestion work I do, and I've found something problematic after upgrading from Outlook 2003 to 2007.

(Had to upgrade to get around a RTF Body issue in OL2003 ..)

Even after you instruct Outlook to close the PST store, Log off and then destroy the object (set objNS = Nothing, etc.), Outlook still hangs around for 1-30 seconds depending on the size of the PST files I'm working with.

I can easily workaround and put in a delay (Wscript.Sleep(300)) but I find this dirty and don't trust it completely ... any ideas on how to get Outlook to close properly?

I have also tried polling for the instance via GetObject() but it seems that it returns False even when OUTLOOK.EXE is still visible in Task Manager.

Code I'm using below:

```
Function TestPSTInOutlook(strFileName)
' Open PST in Outlook then closes it, primarily to determine
' if Outlook has any difficulty in processing the PST in the
' first place.  Not interested in corruptions per message, just
' PST-wide (and passwords).

    Const olMailItem = 0
    Const olMSG = 3
    Const olDiscard = 1

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objOL       ' Outlook.Application   
    Dim objNS       ' Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder   ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objIS       ' Outlook.Inspector 
    Dim objMail     ' Outlook.MailItem

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    objNS.Logon
    objNS.AddStore strFileName

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        loggit_silent = True
        loggit("TestPSTInOutlook(): failed to open " & strFileName & " for reason: " & Err.Description)
        loggit_silent = False
        TestPSTInOutlook = False
    Else
        Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetLast
        objFolder.Name = strFileName

        Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
        Set objIS = objMail.GetInspector 

        objIS.Close (olDiscard) 
        objMail.Close (olDiscard)

        objNS.RemoveStore objFolder
        loggit_silent = True
        loggit("TestPSTInOutlook(): success opening " & strFileName)
        loggit_silent = False
        TestPSTInOutlook = True
    End If

' BUG: Outlook 2007 refuses to shut down when told and takes its time - we have to wait otherwise we error  on trying to move the next PST file ...
' Does not exist in OL2003 but if we roll back then we don't get fixed Unicode PST support and degraded  ingestion performance
' 

    objNS.Logoff 
    objOL.Session.Logoff 
    objOL.Quit 

    Set objIS = Nothing 
    Set objMail = Nothing 
    Set objNS = Nothing 
    Set objOL = Nothing 

    Wscript.sleep(300)
End Function
```

NB: loggit() is purely a logging function (sends to stdout and to a debuglog.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a function like this to see if outlook.exe is still running

```
Function IsRunning(procName)
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & procName & "'")
    If colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
        request = True
    Else
        request = False
    End If
    Set colProcesses = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    IsRunning = request
End Function
```

Then you can just run a loop until the function returns false Something like this

```
Do While IsRunning("notepad.exe")
Loop
```

Comment: Strangely enough it seems to work most of the time, then I get a once off problem where it thinks the process has closed but the lock hadn't cleared in time and failed to move - only with large PSTs (2-10 GB)

I've had to do two things:
 * Keep the creation of the inspector code in place - it actually seems to speed the shutdown of Outlook from 10 seconds to about 2 seconds if you create then destroy the Inspector
 * Implement a subroutine that calls FSO.MoveFile, if it fails, waits 300ms then tries again - this also helps if the system is running with higher than expected CPU as well :(

Comment: Adding correct answer because it works well in the lab either way - other people may get different mileage I guess, thank you Tester101 :)